# How to restart BackgroundService from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created WcBackgroundService (inherit by BackgroundService) and I'm injecting it to OrdersController. When frontend API sends request on restart endpoint I'll execute Restart method from my worker.

As above, current solution doesn't restart service only create new instance of my background service and start it.

Below is my code

WcBackgroundService

```
public async Task Restart()
{
    await StopAsync(new CancellationToken());
    await StartAsync(new CancellationToken());
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     cancellationToken.Register(() =>
     {
         _logger.Debug($"Service {_serviceType} is stopping.");
     });

     while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         await DoWork();
     }
}
```

ConfigureServices in Startup:

```
..
services.AddSingleton<IWcBackgroundService, WcBackgroundService>();
..
```

Configure in Startup:

```
var wcBackgroundService = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IWcBackgroundService>();
wcBackgroundService.StartAsync(new CancellationToken()).Wait();
```

Comment: I saw this task and register my BackgroundService like services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyBackgroundService>(); (IWcBackgroundService inherit by IHostedService)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cancel on THE SAME token, which is passed at the start, only then will it cancel the background task.

You should implement cancellation in your task, cancel through the token which you properly pass through and store in somewhere, for example implement a task management service which you register as a singleton in your DI container (you can also get the token from your wcBackGroundService if you expose it through a property), then implement a controller endpoint let's say "RestartBackgroundTask" which get's the token or tokenSource from the singleton service and cancels it, then calls the start method again. You can move the task.Start into a separate function so you can all the same logic without code duplication.

[Read about cancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks, it's working :) I created CancellationTokenSource which is canceled in Restart method. After canceling I've to wait for finish current job and then Start with new CancellationTokenSource

Comment: Sub tip as you are using async-await patterns. Don't wait with Task.Wait() or xy.Result. ALWAYS use xyTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult() or just await it.

Comment: While working on something similar I ran into an issue because I was passing the same cancellation token to the stop and the start method. My oversight was that the stop method in the background service calls `.Cancel()` on the token, so you need to create a new cancellation token if you want to start it again

Comment: @MariuszD. Will you please post a sample code which works for you ? I'm also facing same issue. Thanks in advance.